# Angular ng build --prod throwing error with combination of array and string in a object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have declare the object value in ts file like below.

```
public saveFissionParams:any = {};
```

It contains different properties is given below,

```
public saveFissionParams:any = {
    jobList:[],
    triggerList:[],
    dependencyList:[],
    fissionName:'',
    fissionInstanceId:'',
    options:false,
    note:'',

  };
```

The jobList, triggerList, dependencyList for looping the data in view.
 The fissionName, fissionInstanceId, options, note is in the form decleared into the ngModel its looks like below.

```
<textarea rows="10" class="form-control" name="note" id="note"  [(ngModel)]="saveFissionParams.note"  ></textarea>
```

When trying to be ng build --prod getting the below error.

```
Property 'note' does not ex
ist on type '{ jobList: any[]; triggerList: any[]; dependencyList: any[]; fissionInstanceId: string; }'.
```

Can anyone please help me out. What I am missing here.

Comment: Have you declare whole saveFissionParams in your ts file as you have written in second code?

Comment: Yes I have declared inside ngOnInit                                                                                                                      `ngOnInit() {

   
    this.saveFissionParams = {
      jobList:[],
      triggerList:[],
      dependencyList:[],
      fissionName:'',
      fissionInstanceId:'',
      options:false,
      note:'',
    }
  }`

Comment: Put it in your constructor and check it again...

Comment: Where are you setting the `note` property in your code?

Comment: Tried, but same response...

Comment: @ExplosionPills in the html file ngModel like as `[(ngModel)]="saveFissionParams.note"`

Comment: You need to declare the type or set a default value for `.note` in the component

Comment: @ExplosionPills can u please explain me how to declare or set the value, am newbie for Angular 4

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue actually; we may need more code to help debug

Comment: I will create link and shared with you the code in JsFiddle.. As of now can u tell me how to declare or set the value in component for `.note` property

Comment: Can we have array property and string property inside the object in the component.. Array values are not bind to ngModel but string and boolean values are binding to the ngModel. Is it make any difference?

Comment: If you are writing public saveFissionParams:any = {}; and also writing whole saveFissionParams object  in your ts file then just write whole object in constructor, I think it will work and no then can you please past your ts file so I can get better idea about issue.